# Registros MX diferentes para Servidores de e-mail diferentes

Tags: email, servidor, dns, cpanel

Tenho dois servidores o Y (apenas para e-mail), e tenho o Servidor Z (vazio).
-O servidor Y possui algumas contas de e-mails cadastradas;
-o Z quero cadastrar apenas 2 contas de email e usá-las sem a intervenção do servidor Y.
É possível realizar a configuração de dois servidores, e que possam receber e-mails normalmente com o mesmo domínio e sem o conflito de ambos...? Resumindo: cada um em seu quadrado?

Exemplo: Servidor Y:
email1@email.com
email2@email.com

Servidor Z:
email3@email.com
email4@email.com

Comment: Não é possível. Quem resolve o lado "esquerdo" da @ é o servidor de email, e para isto você já tem que ter conectado nele (ou seja, depois da resolução de DNS). Se quiser dividir as contas em servidores diferentes, precisa que o servidor apontado no MX repasse os emails internamente, depois do recebimento. Ainda, você pode ter mais de um MX diferente, mas não vai depender da conta qual deles vai atender ao pedido. De qualquer forma, a pergunta não está no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Boa noite! O problema é que isso não tem a ver com programação.

Comment: Tem razão pessoal, desculpem pelo deslize. Mas obrigado pela info @Bacco